# MariaDB load data infile permission error

Tags: csv, permissions, mariadb

I am attempting to load data into a MariaDB database. The ownership of the directory loaded from was modified as follows:

```
$ chown -R mysql load_data
```

permissions for the directory appear as:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 mysql    beta_user 4096 Jul 20 16:33 load_data
```

The data file, **emp_list.dat**, looks as follows:

```
Dineen,,Tim,Frog,1965-03-17
Blatter,,Greg,Butterfly,1975-10-18
Hank,Larry,Kevin,Aligator,1980-02-03
Jones,,Tom,Singer,1945-04-04
```

The load command in **load_employees.sql** is as follows:

```
load data infile       
'/home/beta_user/sample_code/db/mariadb/load_data/emp_list.dat'
into table pktest.employees
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(last_name,middle_name,first_name,pref_name,@dob)
set dob = str_to_date(@dob, '%y-%m-%d');
```

When I attempt to load data the following error appears:

> $ mysql --defaults-file=~/bin/msqlpsw/msqlpkpsw.dat -D pktest -e "source /home/beta_user/sample_code/db/mariadb/load_data/load_employees.sql"
>   ERROR 13 (HY000) at line 1 in file:  '/home/beta_user/sample_code/db/mariadb/load_data/load_employees.sql':
>   Can't get stat of '/home/beta_user/sample_code/db/mariadb/load_data/emp_list.dat'
>   (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")

Can anybody suggest why the error given that the ownership of the directory is set to mysql ?

Comment: Can you post the result of `ps aux | grep mysql`

Comment: `$ ps aux | grep mysql
mysql     3168  0.0  0.9 986304 152560 ?       Ssl  09:11   0:19 /usr/sbin/mysqld
beta_user 13101  0.0  0.0  14228   944 pts/2    S+   18:08   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
`

Comment: You can try with: `chown -R mysql:mysql load_data`...then check with `stat load-data`, and now, restart the database service

Comment: Performed following
`$ sudo chown -R mysql:mysql load_data/
[sudo] password for beta_user: 
$ ls -ltr
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 129 Jul 20 14:56 emp_list.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mysql mysql 277 Jul 21 09:46 load_employees.sql`
BUT when load run again, same error:
`$ mysql --defaults-file=~/bin/msqlpsw/msqlpkpsw.dat -D pktest -e "source ~/sample_code/db/mariadb/load_data/load_employees.sql"
ERROR 13 (HY000) at line 1 in file: '~/sample_code/db/mariadb/load_data/load_employees.sql': Can't get stat of '~/sample_code/db/mariadb/load_data/emp_list.dat' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")`

Comment: Just for testing purposes, try `chmod 777 /home/beta_user/sample_code/db/mariadb/load_data/emp_list.dat'`